# Minimum gap between adjacent elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a method that prints the minimum gap between 2 adjacent values in an array full of integers. My code compiles but I think my formula might be wrong. The end result should be just one minimum value. Any suggestions?

```
public static void minGap(int[] list) { //pass it an array of random integers
    int min = 0;
    int gap = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { //cycle through the array
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            gap = ((i + 1) - i);
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is " + gap + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this output? Also can you format your code better?

Comment: `gap = ((i+1) - i) ;` Think about what this is doing...

Comment: The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1 
The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is 1

Comment: If you did it by hand, would you iterate twice on the array? Then why does your algorithm do that? Don't you think that to find the *minimum* gap, you would need to compare gaps together? And what's this min variable that is used nowhere?

Comment: I supposed I just need to iterate through one time and the Min variable was there because I need to compare that lowest value with a minimum value of some sort. Confused on how to go about it though.

Comment: How would you do this task if you had to do it by hand, i.e., what are the steps involved and what do you keep track of? Next, how would you write out the instructions for another person to do this task so that they know what to keep track of and there would be no confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void minGap(int[] list) { //pass it an array of random integers
   // initialize gap with difference of first two elements of array             
   int gap = Math.abs(list[1] - list[0]);
   // Start the array iteration from second element as we already have difference of first two elements.
   for(int i = 2; i < list.length; i++) { //cycle through the array
      // calculate the difference between two adjacent element. 
      int absDiff = Math.abs(list[i] - list[i-1]); 
      // if the difference is less then the prior minimum it becomes the new minimum.
      if(gap > absDiff) {           
         gap = absDiff;
      }
   }
   System.out.println("The minimum gap between 2 adjacent values is " + gap + " "); 
}
```

Comment: You might want an absolute value in there somewhere.  Also, recalculating the difference is ugly. Finally, imho, giving people a solution to their homework is not really doing them favors - hints and explanations are better.

Comment: This is not very useful, if you're going to post code you better explain what you're doing.

Comment: yes. you are right .I assume that numbers are in ascending order. Are you saying that we can derive minimum gap without calculating the difference between two adjacent elements ?

Comment: the numbers are not in ascending order they are just random depending on how large the user specified the array to be.

Comment: 1) `Math.abs` would be ever so much cleaner. 2) Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Seems like having the array already sorted would save a lot of headache. If it's already in ascending order then you wouldn't have to worry about absolute value correct? In other words having negative numbers.

Comment: @user3697635 Sorting the array is much more work than taking `Math.abs(list[i] - list[i-1])`. Sorting within your method would alter the original input, which might cause harm in other parts of your program.  Requiring the user of your method to do the sorting before passing the array to you would require that you check the sortedness (more work) or make your method fragile (easily breaks when the user doesn't comply). Absolute value is by far the cleanest solution.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class minGapClass
{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] list = {3, 1, 6, 12, 7};
    int minResult = minGap(list);
    System.out.println(minResult);

}
  public static int minGap(int[] list){

    if (list.length < 2){
        return 0;
    }
    int min = list[1] - list[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++){
        if (min > list[i+1] - list[i]){
             min = list[i+1] - list[i];
        } 
    }
    return min;
}
}
```